# auto pass password to su (no sudo)

Tags: command-line, ssh, password, su

I am trying to pipe a password into su so that I can run su in a script and automatically give it a password. I am running this without sudo and attempting to su into root. I have tried this a few different ways including

```
echo pa$$w0rd | su
```

and

```
su <<!                
> pa$$w0rd
> ls
> !
```

No matter how I try to accomplish this I get the error message:

```
su: must be run from a terminal
```

I am using ssh with the -t flag so that I have a pty. I have already confirmed that I can su into root if I manually enter the password. Is there a way I can automate the password input?

Comment: "so that I can run su in a script " Bad idea: your password WILL be visible to others that have access to the machine.  "to su into root" we do not use root on Ubuntu. We use an admin account. The file `/etc/sudoers`  can be used to create exceptions for "sudo" usage.  https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Sudoers That is the way to go on systems that use sudo ;) Even if you are able to do it like this the pty allocation is not going to happen for the same reason.

Comment: AFAIK you would need to use something like `expect` to script the interaction - but this sounds like an x-y problem